# Javascript doesn't get executed the first time when I access a page from a link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

There's a template in my rails application that doesn't execute the javascript code the first time when it is loaded by clicking on a link in my home page. It only happens when it's accessed from the link and only the first time. I don't know why is this happening. Any help? Here is the code.

Home page:

```
#app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
#...
<%= link_to "Nofify an absence", new_cancellation_path %>
```

this is the Javascript file:

```
//app/assets/javascripts/cancellations_new.js

var validateDateTime = function(){
// some other code that returns true or false
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_cancellation").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      if (validateDateTime()) {
        alert("Some alert");
      }
      else { 
        // some more code 
      }
    }); 
  });
```

And the template where the javascript should be executed:

```
#app/views/cancellations/new.erb

<%= provide(:title, "Notify an absence")%>
<div class="row">
<div class="span3 offset4">
  <h3> Notify an absence </h3>

  <%= form_for @cancellation, :id => "new_cancellation" do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <% # some form elements...%>
    <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary"%>        
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

I have already tried adding `//= require cancellations_new` to the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` with no improvement

**EDIT**

I did some research, following @radubogdan lead and I found that Turbolinks is responsible for the "strange" behavior of Javascript. If you have Turbolinks activated in your application, the `<a>` elements get loaded from an Ajax request, and then the content is used to modify the `<body>` of your HTML. Since the way the DOM is loaded is not the usual one, the code written inside of

`$(document).ready(){...}`

won't work unless the page is fully reloaded (for example refreshing the browser).  If you want your Javascript to run as usual, you might have to change your

`$(document).ready(){...}`

to

`$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  // some more code.
});`

You can find some more info about this topic [here](http://staal.io/blog/2013/01/18/dangers-of-turbolinks/)
[more](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works)

Comment: Do you have turbolinks activated?

Comment: Did you tried to deactivate it? Remove it from application.js and from layout.html.erb where you use stylesshet link tag. If it works without turbolinks, then you should checkout how to use `$(document).on('page:load', .....)`

Comment: The behavior is the same without turbolinks.

Comment: Hi @radubogdan , I found out the way to make it work, but I don't fully understand why. First, I removed `//= require_tree .` from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and then I added `<%= javascript_include_tag "cancellations_new"%>` in the end of `app/views/cancellations/new.erb` . Now it works fine from the beginning. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi @felix. Sometimes rails is too magic and it's going to take you too much time to solve problems like this one.. I'm glad it worked.

Comment: @radubogdan I realized that I didn't solve the problem. So I follow your lead and I researched about Turbolinks and, indeed, was the cause of the Javascript not working. Thank you so much for the help. If you want to post and answer I'll accept it as correct. Also a +1 to my question won't hurt anybody. I'm new here. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you tried really hard to fix this and I'm glad I helped you. I'll upvote you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think turbolinks is the problem. Did you try to deactivate it?

Remove it from `application.js` and from `layout.html.erb` where you use stylesheet link tag.

If it works without turbolinks, then you should checkout how to use

`$(document).on('page:load', .....)`

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

just add in your `application.html.erb`

```
<body data-no-turbolink="true" >
  # your content
</body>
```

**OR**

add this to your gem-file

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

BOTH WILL WORK AS PER YOUR EXPECTION.